# Как переделать модуль для DLE в обычный php-скрипт?

Tags: php, dle

Как переделать модуль для DLE в обычный php-скрипт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вырезать либо заменить (что нельзя просто так вырезать) чем-то все что относится к дле. странный вопрос.

Comment: но намного проще убедт понять как модуль работает и написать самостоятельно.